# pointer caused error message in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>   

void Strcat(char* a, char* b);   

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char c[]  = "abcdefg";
    char d[]  = "hijklmn";
    Strcat(c, d);
    printf("%s\n",c); 
}

void Strcat(char* a, char* b)
{
    for(; *a!= '\0';a++);

    for(; *b != '\0';a++,b++)
    {
        *a = *b;
    } 
}
```

The function is intended to copy String d at the end of c. It worked but compiler (XCode) gives me some feedback as follows:

```
    0x7fff50716e34 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax   ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x7fff50716e39 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff50716e3c <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x7fff50716e3e <+10>: jae    0x7fff50716e48.    ; <+20> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    0x7fff50716e40 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff50716e43 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff5070e0b8     ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff50716e48 <+20>: retq   
    0x7fff50716e49 <+21>: nop    
    0x7fff50716e4a <+22>: nop    
    0x7fff50716e4b <+23>: nop
```

The error message looks like a kind of assembly that I hardly understand. I am new in C so could someone pls tell me what that means?

Comment: What happens after the first loop in `strcat`?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Very annoying curly brackets placement.

Comment: What is the value of *a and *b after the second loop? What do you expect? (and,yes: c[] is too small)

Comment: Also, turn on all your compiler warnings, and fix them. Compiler warnings are notices from the people who wrote the tool you're using to processes your code into an executable object that your code might be legal but it's not really right. Given they know enough to write a compiler *and put in the extra effort to produce a warning that the C standard doesn't require*, it's a **really** good idea to listen to their warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: basic knowledge of C needed - do you understand how much memory c[]="dfdfdf" allocates and how strcat works? Read the strcat documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Array `c` is too small to store the concatenation of its initial value and `d`. You are writing outside of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Take a hint from the documentation of the standard [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function:

> Appends a copy of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by src
>   to the end of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by dest. The
>   character src[0] replaces the null terminator at the end of dest. The
>   resulting byte string is null-terminated.
>
> **The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large
>   enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null
>   character**. The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap. The
>   behavior is undefined if either dest or src is not a pointer to a
>   null-terminated byte string.